# Flowtype, React and defaultProps

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flowtype

After hours of searchs and tests, I didn't succeed to find any solution to make flow understand defaultProps

See [Try Flow example](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQBLAtgB1gJwC6gEoCmAhgMY4A0oA3qAAoCuWhAwrBrAHaGd4C+oSFnagA5MzI5RAbkRzEwAFRyAogA900Yp2I5kXAM4AuOQFpQpYumQ5i0ZAC9CAMWRYDOADKEcOQlgAKAEpQbkIAEwNQHFhQZlJCZAA3QlBiUA8sZE4AcwA6RHMAHm9ffzAAPlB4ZGhoUHDYgCJLa1t7J1d3Lx8-QINHQiCm6psACzSMwdAx4iTsnMnwwkhiBmg8dGF0AwLzJoGnEcbCA05RPANCQlRo2IAjVOXV9ZxTLdh0UxwAT3QIuSKYDyeSkQx4Vo2OyDLoeUp9UAAXlAAUyRgyOCyuSC6MyCyRVUyAG0AAwAXTyMQAquh-lgWMQrsFQABqDFYPIGewJAIARiCsjkv3+9G2BgAKn9UsjqAAfRCgKZOAD86NEBlQdmgolAsrE92QOVEFEQsr4gsQpC0Bii8P8oEIaj8nEi9CYrHYmG4vCKdDFkv+VWockVHl0yFIDRWaw2fs+URlCsVSsIao1WuNSb4IbiPGWgRCweTFnBNBToAEyJwY2Quw+O0FxbBnA8glgsWRkPaMLccN6-lRgwFOcVzBwTE4bdgskV2cQc5AoBK-awlUQQA)

Using this model is unconsitent:

```js
type PropsType = {|
  size?: 'small' | 'big',
|};


class Letter extends PureComponent<PropsType> {

  static defaultProps = {
    size: 'small',
  }

}
```

Thanks

#### Edit

After Tomasz Mularczyk's suggestion, I created [another Try Flow example](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQBLAtgB1gJwC6gEoCmAhgMY4A0oA3qAAoCuWhAwrBrAHaGd4C+oSFnagA5MzI5RAbkRzgAKjkBRAB7poxTsRzIuAZwBccgLShSxdMhzFoyAF6EAYsiz6cAGUI4chLAAoASlBuQgATfVAcWFBmUkJkADdCUGJQdyxkTgBzADpEMwAeLx8-MAA+UHhkaGhQMJiAIgsrGztHFzdPb18A-QdCQMaq6wALVPSB0FHiRKzsibDCSGIGaDx0YXR9fLNG-sdhhsJ9TlE8fUJCVCiYgCMUpZW1nBNN2HQTHABPdHC5BTAOTAxCkAx4FrWWwDTruEq9UAAXlA-gyhjE+lQtmgolAAB8xHdkNlRIF0Rl5kjKhkANoABgAurlogBVdB-LAsYiXIKgADU6RwWFy+js8X8AEZArI5D8-vQtvoACq-FLI6h4xCgSaOdGiTHY3EE0REkkURB4vgy0GafSReF+UCEVS+TgRehMVjsTDcXiFOiKlV-SrUOTa9w6ZCkerLVbrAMfSLqrXanWEPUAIQAggARUA55ROLMsjxK+j4ADydAAyqJzdq+GHYjwlgFgqHU+ZwTQ06ABMicKNkDt3tsZZ2wZx3IJYDFkZC2jDXHCen5UQNpU3tcwcExODPYLIG3JG4gQKBiqusBVEEA) with:

```js
type PropsType = {|
  size: 'small' | 'big',
|};
```

instead of

```js
type PropsType = {|
  size?: 'small' | 'big',
|};
```

**But**

defaultProp `size` is not typed anymore:

```js
static defaultProps = {
  size: 'BAD DEFAULT PROPS', // no error (?!)
}
```

---

## Solution

See Tomasz Mularczyk's answer

+

Don't wait flow error on your current component ( in my case), but where it will be imported and declared.(seems semi-static no?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just remove `?` from `size` type. Flow will automatically see that you created `defaultProps` and will not require it.

From [docs:](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/components/#toc-using-default-props)

> To type default props add a static defaultProps property to your
>   class.

...

> React also supports default props on stateless functional components.
>   Similarly to class components, default props for stateless functional
>   components will work without any extra type annotations.

Comment: If I remove the `?` from `size` PropsType, the `static defaultProps` become useless, and this will generate runtime proptypes warning cause the `size` prop won't be passed

Comment: @MadeInMoon Flow is able to "see" that you have declared default property for a required prop. And will not require it when you use that component.

Comment: thanks for your time. See my edit above with an other Try Flow example

Comment: found the solution: remove the ? from size PropsType + and don't wait errors in the current component but when it will be imported and declared!

Comment: @MadeInMoon thanks for sharing, I wouldn't think about it :)